# How to select the value of a specific text field when they all have the same class name

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-traversing

I have a table which is generated using a foreach in PHP (Laravel). The table has 3 columns: "Name", "Notes" and "Deactivate". Deactivate is a select with options, "Activate and "Inactive".  The "Name" column is made up of a text input field with the `class=name`. "Deactivate" option has a class of `edit_cat`.

```
<tr>
   <td>{{ Form::text("category_name[]",$category->name,['class'=>'name',])}}</td>
   <td>{{ Form::text("notes[]",$category->notes)}}</td>
   <td>{{ Form::select("category_value[]",['active'=>'Active' ,'inactive' => 'Inactive'],$category->status,['class'=>'edit_cat'])}}</td>
</tr>
```

When I select an option from column 3,"deactivate", my JQuery needs to also grab the text value of the "category_name" in column one.

I have tried everything I can find in the JQuery API, and here in SO. I have used `closest` and `find`, with `input:text .name` OR, `td.name` or a dozen other permutations.But I only get `undefined` back, or an error.

```
 $(".edit_cat").on("change", function () {
       var value =  $(this).closest(".name-input").val();
       console.log(value);
    });
```

What am I doing wrong? Many Thanks !

Comment: `var value =  $(this).closest("tr").find(".name-input").val();` you almost got it mate. use closest to find its closest parent. input is just a sibling. you need to do closest parent which is tr then find the specific input try the code about

Comment: Brilliant Thank You !! It works ! I had to slightly adjust the `find` to `.find("td .name")`  If you were to put this in the answer I could give you an up vote ! Cheers

Comment: I will put it an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var value = $(this).closest("tr").find("td .name").val();`

You almost got it mate.

1. Use closest to find its closest parent because input is just a sibling.
2. You need to do closest parent which is `tr` then find the specific input.

[closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)

> Description: For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree.